# Quick notification silence

Tags: android, notifications

The primary purpose of my app is to change a smart phone into a sort of smart pager (there is an associated web app, but that's not the purpose of the Android app). I use the Notification system built in to Android to handle alerting the user that they have received a page.

My problem is that the clients want:

1. The notification ringer to ring forever until acknowledged (easily accomplished with FLAG_INSISTENT)
2. **An easy way to silence the ringer with 1 push of a button**. It is really not always feasible due to the nature of their work to press the power button, slide to unlock, and drag down the notification bar. I need to replicate the behavior of a pager.

I need to find a way to satisfy the 2nd requirement. It looks like I can hook into keypresses if I've got an activity running, but of course, when a notification is received, the screen will probably be off. I am looking into this currently, but I was wondering if anyone had some guidance in the meantime.

Does anyone have ideas on how I could accomplish this goal? Are there alternative ways to listen for key presses, or some creative combination of flags that could get me there?

Techniques that would normally be frowned on for Market apps are completely on the table, since the phones are owned by my employer and will only be used by other employees. I just want to avoid using private or deprecated APIs to make switching phone models easier for the developer who eventually inherits this project.

Thank you to everyone for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have ideas on how I could accomplish this goal?

You'd have to hold a `WakeLock`, specifically a `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`, in order to respond to button presses. This means that battery life will be sucktastic, unless you put some time limit on that (e.g., hold the `WakeLock` for a minute or two, but otherwise assume the user's not near the device, so don't keep it awake).

You would also need to try to interrupt the keyguard with `KeyguardManager`. I have not done this so I do not know all of the details. Your "watch for the magic button" logic would have to be in the activity that appears on top of the keyguard.

Also, bear in mind that not all Android devices have physical buttons -- in fact, I would not be the least bit surprised if the whole physical button metaphor goes "poof" with Ice Cream Sandwich later this year. Hence, the button in question really should be an on-screen `Button` for future-proofing.

Comment: Thanks for your great ideas. I think having a "notification" activity sounds appealing as a way to improve the in-hand experience, though my perfect solution would allow them to keep the phone in their pocket or clipped on their belt.

Comment: I'm thinking of holding the wake lock for 30 sec or so and using KeyguardManager to unlock the screen and have an activity showing with a giant "Acknowledge" button or something, that way they can try to hit it in their pocket. I'll also listen for the power button.

Comment: That will teach me to look at a random SO answer without verifying. I think the volume rockers will work fine. If we can't find any phones with those in 2 years, we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

Comment: @WorkerThread: Yeah, the volume rocker probably will be the last to go, and I suspect they may be around for most phones for a long time. It wouldn't shock me if tablets drop the volume buttons, though.